# docker buildx fails to show result in image list

Tags: docker, docker-build, buildx

The following commands do not show the output `ubuntu1` image:

```
docker buildx build -f 1.dockerfile -t ubuntu1 .
docker image ls | grep ubuntu1
# no output
```

1.dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN echo "my ubuntu"
```

Plus, I cannot use the image in `FROM` statements in other docker files (both builds are on my local Windows box):

2.dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu1
RUN echo "my ubuntu 2"
```

```
docker buildx build -f 2.dockerfile -t ubuntu2 .

#error:
WARNING: No output specified for docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load
[+] Building 1.8s (4/4) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from 2.dockerfile                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 84B                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu1:latest                                                                                                                                       1.8s
 => [auth] library/ubuntu1:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu1:latest:
------
2.dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM ubuntu1:latest
   2 |     RUN echo "my ubuntu 2"
   3 |
--------------------
error: failed to solve: ubuntu1:latest: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed (did you mean ubuntu:latest?)
```

Any idea what's going on? How can I see what buildx prepared and reference one image in another dockerfile?

Comment: you use 2.dockerfil , but command use 1.dockerfile,   `docker buildx build -f 1.dockerfile -t ubuntu1 .`

Comment: `docker buildx build -f 1.dockerfile -t ubuntu1 .` is ok, I test it on my pc, it ok. My Env: Ubuntu 20.04, $ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.21
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.7
 Git commit:        baeda1f
 Built:             Tue Oct 25 18:02:21 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
....

Comment: this was a typo of course, I updated the command to build 2.dockerfile

Comment: Refer to [this comment](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/59#issuecomment-1168619521). You need to use the `--load` flag, to load each of the images built, so that they show up in the list returned by `docker images` command

Answer (score 27):

Ok found a partial solution, I need to add `--output type=docker` as per [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#output). This puts the docker in the image list. But I still cannot use it in the second docker.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while working in a pipeline of CI/CD, it was really difficult to understand why it was happening.

But as [devatherock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10435528/devatherock) mentioned in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74707530/docker-buildx-fails-to-show-result-in-image-list/77663132?noredirect=1#comment134598475_74707530), you need to only add the `--load` flag to your build command.

Comment: Both your links are to the user profile, not the comment.